# Change default language for TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I have an installation of Team Foundation Server 2018.  The problem is the web interface defaults to English (United States).  I need to change this to English (Canada) as the default but this is not in the Language drop down.

The Windows Server is set to use English (Canada) so I need to know how to update TFS.  The main reason I need this is that the US write their dates backwards and this causes all sort of issues with work tracking as people assume the date is the correct way around and we end up with tasks due on the 11th of January when they should be for the 1st of November.

I know one possible work around would be for everyone to set their language specifically to English (United States) and then change the default date pattern so the date is correct, but this is not satisfactory as it involves work on the part of hundreds of users.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is to configure Windows to send the primary browser locale as 'en-CA', this can be done through an Active Directory Policy, with TFS configured to use "Browser" as locale it should default to the correct date format for that locale.

[image]

(See the locale switching to "Nederlands (Nederland)" which is my locale)

If users are using a different browser, they may have to configure that as well, for example, my Chrome configuration:
[image]

Alternatively, you can set the language for each users in the  TFS Configuration Database for individual users. It can be overridden there in bulk.

**THIS IS NOT SUPPORTED AND MAY LEAVE YOU IN A BROKEN STATE**

```
update [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_RegistryItems]
set
      [RegValue] = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
where 
      ParentPath LIKE '#\Users\%\UserPreferences\'
      and ChildItem = 'DatePattern\'

insert into [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_RegistryItems]
    (PartitionId, ParentPath, ChildItem, RegValue)
    select
        1 as PartitionId, 
        '#\Users\' + lower(convert(nvarchar(36), tbl_Identity.Id)) + '\UserPreferences\' as ParentPath,
        'DatePattern\' as ChildItem,
        'dd-MM-yyyy' as RegItem
    from tbl_Identity
    where 
        IsGroup = 0
        and Domain = 'AzureAD'
        and not exists
        (
            select 1 from [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_RegistryItems]
            where ParentPath = '#\Users\' + lower(convert(nvarchar(36), tbl_Identity.Id)) + '\UserPreferences\'
            and ChildItem = 'DatePattern\'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the language settings in **locale -> user profile**  do not include all language option such as English (Canada).

According to your description, you could simply change **Date pattern** under the preferred language which basically contains all the options,

[image]

For example, select **d-MM-yy**, then 1st of November should be 01/11/2018.

Comment: As stated in the question this is not an acceptable answer.  I am setting up a TFS environment so selecting my own date pattern will not apply to the hundred of other users or future users who will be added to the system.  I need the default date pattern to be correct for all users in the system.

Comment: @Beakster I understand your concern, you need some thing like server-level language setting which will affect  all users's web portal. However, it's impossible and not support. The default language setting of TFS web portal which is  based on your browser's Language setting such as `Browser:xxx(xx)`. However this will not effect the date pattern.  According to the name of setting tab "**LOCALE**", which is very clear. Unfortunately, this is the only solution for now : notify all other users to change their data pattern  for their own account (One time effort). You could not set for them.

Comment: This would also involve all future users having to make the change.  It really becomes maintainable at this point.  

The browser language and culture are set correctly but as TFS doesnt seem to have en-uk or en-ca it goes to en-us.

There is no excuse for not supporting cultures.  It is a massive oversight on the part of Microsoft and if there isn't a solution to it then this is another reason for us to migrate to Jira.

Comment: @Beakster We are sorry for the trouble caused. You could submit a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion and follow up. Besides you could also add a case in TFS  [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) site. Double confirm it and see if they could provide another alternative method.